# Extract coordinates from .gpx file with OpenLayers (or any other JS library)?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gpx

I have a simple drag and drop event assigned to my OpenLayers map. This allows me to take a .gpx file, drag & drop it on top of my map which results in the route being visualized on the map.

The code looks like this (taken from the official OpenLayers examples [docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html)):

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import DragAndDrop from 'ol/interaction/DragAndDrop';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {GPX, GeoJSON, IGC, KML, TopoJSON} from 'ol/format';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {Vector as VectorSource, XYZ} from 'ol/source';

const key = 'Get your own API key at https://www.maptiler.com/cloud/';
const attributions =
  '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> ' +
  '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>';

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        attributions: attributions,
        url:
          'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=' + key,
        maxZoom: 20,
      }),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

const extractStyles = document.getElementById('extractstyles');
let dragAndDropInteraction;

function setInteraction() {
  if (dragAndDropInteraction) {
    map.removeInteraction(dragAndDropInteraction);
  }
  dragAndDropInteraction = new DragAndDrop({
    formatConstructors: [
      GPX,
      GeoJSON,
      IGC,
      // use constructed format to set options
      new KML({extractStyles: extractStyles.checked}),
      TopoJSON,
    ],
  });
  dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function (event) {
    const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
      features: event.features,
    });
    map.addLayer(
      new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource,
      })
    );
    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
  });
  map.addInteraction(dragAndDropInteraction);
}
setInteraction();
```

My question is: how can I get an array of all of the coordinates from the .gpx file? Is there a JS library that would allow me to extract the lat and long from the .gpx file in-browser, without having to send the xml to the server for processing?

An ideal output would look like this:
`{[lat, lon], [lat, lon], [lat, lon]}`

Comment: Do you want to get GPX coordinates after you drop GPX file on OL map?

Comment: @TomazicM thanks for the reply - yes. I would like to get the recorded coordinates along the whole route or track (eg. a hiking route)

Comment: And why do you have `python` and `openlayers-2` tags?

Comment: Will fix the tag, my bad. Open-layers-2 is there since we the question is about... OL :-) I don't mind if the solution offered by someone refers to the deprecated OL version.

Comment: Posted example is not OpenLayers 2 though, it's latest version (6.9....).  openlayers tag is for openlayers issues from version 3 onward.  i.e. You should have either openlayers-2 or openlayers tag, but not both

Comment: Okay, removing open-layers-2 then. Done.

Comment: Your ideal output is syntactically wrong. Braces `{ ... }` denote object, and object consists of named properties and their values. You probably want array of coordinates: `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get coordinates from feature geometry with the `.getCoordinates()` method, and you can get feature geometry from feature with the `.getGeometry()` method.

To get all arrays of coordinates to a global variable `allCoords`, you just have to add some code to `dragAndDropInteraction.on` event processing function.

Relevant part of the code could look something like this:

```
var allCoords;

dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function (event) {
  allCoords = [];
  event.features.forEach(function(feature) {
     var featureCoords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
     featureCoords.forEach(function(sectionCoords) {
       allCoords.push(sectionCoords);
     });
  });
  .
  .
  .
});
```

This way `allCoords` would contain coordinates in the map projection, which in this case is Web Mercator, i.e. 'EPSG:3857'.

If you want to get coordinates in `[lon, lat]` format, conversion with the `ol.proj.toLonLat` method is needed:

```
var allCoords;

dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function (event) {
  allCoords = [];
  event.features.forEach(function(feature) {
     var featureCoords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
     featureCoords.forEach(function(sectionCoords) {
       for (var i = 0; i < sectionCoords.length; i++) {
         sectionCoords[i] = ol.proj.toLonLat(sectionCoords[i]);
       }
       allCoords.push(sectionCoords);
     });
  });
  .
  .
  .
});
```